# Git doesn't add my files, even though I add them

Tags: linux, git, shell, github

After adding files in a bunch of different ways, the files are still not added to the commit, no matter which way I am trying to add them. This is my console output so you understand better:

```
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working    directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   .vim/bundle/auto-pairs (modified content)
    modified:   .vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim (modified content)
    modified:   .vim/bundle/emmet-vim (modified content)
    modified:   .vim/bundle/nerdtree (modified content)
    <a lot of files>

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git add *
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git add -A
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git commit -m "Vim bundles"
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   .vim/bundle/auto-pairs (modified content)
    ...
    <same files>

no changes added to commitPdaniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working    directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   .vim/bundle/auto-pairs (modified content)
    <same files>

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git add *
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git add -A
daniel@padamtuts:~/github/dotfiles$ git commit -m "Vim bundles"
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   .vim/bundle/auto-pairs (modified content)
    <same files>

no changes added to commit
```

```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files/directories that begin with `.` are 'hidden' and will be ignored by git when you add with the glob character. You can read about these 'dotfiles' if you want to learn more; usually they are configuration files (e.g. for vim) and such that you may not want to interact with directly and by default will not appear in a file explorer, or in the output of `ls`, etc.

For your purposes, `git add .` should do the trick.

Comment: Although after reading more carefully and seeing that you're putting vim plugins under version control in a directory called 'dotfiles' you probably already know a thing or two :p

Comment: I am back to this problem and I can't add them even with `git add .` It doesn't add them anyways'

Comment: What OS/shell/git version are you using? If you use `git add .vim`, from the same directory do you get the same result?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 17.10. The core of the problem is slightly different though. I fixed the problem by removing all the `.git` folders within each of my bundle files. That way there are no deep file trees. After removing them, everything got added as should be.